# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'matrix' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

> "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation:
>   Data too long for column 'matrix' at row 1"

My matrix column data type is varchar. The data for my matrix column only 12 character. I have increase varchar size from 12 to 30 but still getting the same error. I also have change the data type for matrix column from varchar to longtext but still not success. I'm using netbean to code my java app and mydatabase using mySql.

I already check the similar posting but none the answer can solved my error. tried all available answer for the posting.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Have you restarted your java application after making the changes?

Comment: Please post your SQL command, and include what have you done that works.  MySQL sometimes gives misleading error as well.  Does inserting a string less than 12 characters work?

Comment: try{
            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connected2!");
            
            Statement stmt = (Statement) myConn.createStatement();
                        
            String insert = "INSERT INTO infostudentdb.studinfo (matrix,nama,kelas) VALUES ('"+jtxtmatrix+"','"+jtxtname.getText()+"','"+jtxtClass.getText()+"')";   
            stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
            
        } 

 - i just realize that i forgot to put dot(.) gettext() after jtxtmatrix. TQ for the suggestion.